# How to get the selected dropdown item

Tags: php, html, forms

The below code is what I use to generate a dropdown menu from my database which I finally have working (new to php and mysql).

First of all, have I used the best method for doing so?

Secondly, I would then like to use the selected item to generate an image depending on the category selected once submitted using a button. How can I use the selected item in the drop down menu so that when the form is submitted it can generate the related image?

```
<?php
include_once ("conn.php");
$querydropdown = "SELECT DISTINCT category FROM categorytypes";
$resultcategories = $mysqli->query($querydropdown);

?>

<html>

<head>


</head>

<body>

<select id="categories" class="admindropdown">
    <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
<?php
    while ($rowCerts = $resultcategories->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$rowCerts['category']}\">";
        echo $rowCerts['category'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
?>

</select>

</body>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about "how can I get the selected item" please?

Comment: Either you'll need some sort of JavaScript of you'd need a `<form>` with a submit button. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `name` attribute to your `select`element.

For instance:

```
<select id="categories" class="admindropdown" name="my_dropdown">
    <option selected disabled>Choose one</option>
<?php
    while ($rowCerts = $resultcategories->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<option value=\"{$rowCerts['category']}\">";
        echo $rowCerts['category'];
        echo "</option>";
    }
?>

</select>
```

Then you can get the value using:

`$dropdown_value = $_POST['my_dropdown'];`

Where `my_dropdown` is the value of the `name` attribute of your `select` element.

Also you have to wrap the above code with a `form` element.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
/* CODE HERE */
</form>
```

You can leave the value of `action` attribute empty if you want to access it on the same page.

have fun!

Comment: Thanks so much i will put this to practice asap! Apologies for my brief question i am still new to mysqli and php. Is there any best practices i can apply? e.g. htmlentities / protection?

Comment: The internet has pretty much everything when it comes to best practices. When I started developing with PHP I happen to stumble with this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/30-php-best-practices-for-beginners--net-6194